# JS в WebView выполняется всего 1 раз

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

WebView подключен к index.html (скопирован из asset в память телефона). В index.html подключен JS-файл. В нем есть часть кода, которая работает через `setInterval`. В нем лежит функция, которая возвращает переменную из другого js-файла.

Логика работы: выполняем каждые N секунд "внутренности" `setInterval`. Там натыкаемся на функцию. Она подключает другой скрипт в код. И мы возвращаем нужную переменную в кусок с `setInterval`.

JS-файл с переменной меняется в другой программе, но его структура остается такой же. Изменяется только значение этой переменной.

На компе все работает идеально. А вот в WebView на Android не получается.

Вместо функции "подключить другой файл и считать переменную" делал просто рандомное математическое число. И на компе и в WebView все работает. Поэтому пришел к выводу, что проблема не в `setInterval`. Похоже проблема именно с подключением "внешнего" js-файла. Кажется, он просто не обновляет эту переменную. Или просто отказывается подключать этот скрипт, раз он уже подключен.

Мучался с `web.loadUrl("javascript: test()");` - тоже самое. Не обновляет переменную (ну эт я думаю, что не обновляет).

coord.js:

```
xx =54;
```

Основной JS:

```
   setInterval(function() {
        marker.forEach(function(n) {

    n.setLatLng(new L.LatLng(
        xyz(),
        24
    ))
})
}, 0);

    function xyz(){
        include("coord.js");
        return xx;
    }       

    function include(url) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }
```

Comment: Прочитай про ajax что ли...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас здесь куча ошибок:

- Вы при каждом вызове `setInterval` создаете **новый** тег  `script`, у вас их там миллионы накапливаются.
- Время между вызовами `setInterval` стоит **0** миллисекунд.
- Есть вероятность, что тег `script` не обновляется из-за кеша.
- Загрузка тега `script` происходит асинхронно.
- Также, возможно, у вас не правильно написан цикл. Как-то странно всем маркерам на карте ставить одну и ту же координату.

Попробуйте вот так:

```
setInterval(function () {
  marker.forEach(function (n) {
    xyz(function () {
      n.setLatLng(new L.LatLng(xx, 24));
    });
  });
}, 1000);

function xyz (callback) {
    include('test.js', callback);
}

function include (url, callback) {
    var oldScript = document.getElementById(url);
    if (oldScript)
        oldScript.remove();
    var scr = document.createElement('script');
    scr.id = url;
    scr.src = url + '?t=' + Math.random();
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scr);
    scr.onload = callback;
}
```

Comment: если выставить setInterval =1000, то маркер вообще не ставится. если выставить 0, то ставится 1 раз, но при изменение JS'а ничего не происходит

Comment: @Wlad Я, надеюсь, вы понимаете, что делает функция `setInterval`?

Comment: устанавливает интервал через который будет делаться. 1000 = 1сек. т.е. каждую секунду должно происходить обновление.

Comment: @Wlad Отлично. Теперь, что будет происходить, если интервал равен 0? Это риторический вопрос, ответ я думаю, вы знаете) Вы попробовали использовать мой пример?

Comment: да, конечно. и случайно заметил, что на 1000 не работает, а на 0 хотя бы 1 раз да сработало.

Comment: @Wlad вы пробовали использовать мой пример?

Comment: да, я же про него и пишу вам.

Comment: @Wlad Ну раз вы про него пишите, то пишите подробнее, что происходит.

Comment: "если выставить setInterval =1000, то маркер вообще не ставится. если выставить 0, то ставится 1 раз, но при изменение JS'а ничего не происходит". он не работает так, как предыдущий. у старого был косяк в андроид, но на компе он работал. этот и на компе не работает.

Comment: @Wlad Давайте так, вы мне с подробностями описываете проблемы, а я вам отвечаю. Гадать, что там у вас происходит, желания нет)

Comment: Ты случайное число добавляешь в id, а должен в src.

Comment: @Qwertiy ох елки-палки где мои глаза) Действительно, спасибо.

Comment: А зачем ты его в `include.script` сохраняешь? И ещё, а ты уверен, что в url уже нет вопросика?

Comment: @Qwertiy Насчет вопросика в `url` пускай у ТС голова болит, поскольку здесь есть много что оптимизировать: использовать `setTimeout`, правильно `forEach` использовать. В `include.script` уже не сохраняю.

Comment: Тут не оптимизировать, а переписать всё надо на нормальный ajax. Ещё сохраняешь: `var scr = include.script = document.createElement('script');`

Comment: @Qwertiy еще раз спасибо. А я не уверен, что AJAX то будет работать. У вебвью вроде как нет сервера, нет доступа к файловой системе, это же не электрон.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, ну сервер можно самому в приложении поднять на localhost.